# highcharts subtitle formatting

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to format  highcharts title/subtitle,  so change the color of some words and make some words bold. There seems to be no way to do this using the 'standard'parameters. The line of text is coming from a php variable.
I've tried putting html formatting in the text but that has no effect.

My skills are mostly in PHP and not java so if someone could point me to a piece of code i'd be very gratefull.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title

Of particular interest you will find the "useHTML" parameter.

```
chart.setTitle({ 
    text: '<span style="color:#00ff00;">1stline</span>' + '<br>' + '<span style="color:#ff0000;">2ndline</span>' ,
    useHTML:true
});
```

It enables you to use html tags inside the title. And all the styling will be applied as well.